# What exactly is the syntax error here?

Tags: ocaml

I'm trying to write a function that will return the second smallest number in a list. I keep getting a syntax error but I can't really pinpoint what the issue is. Can I please get help on this?

Deleted code

Comment: I still don't see exactly what is wrong with what I wrote. Can you please pinpoint it for me?

Comment: Do not delete the important part of the question.

Answer (score 1):

You forget to close *local* `let` bindings using `in`. The correct (and indented) code should be:

```
let second_smallest_helper1 lst=
  let second_smallest_helper2 currentMinimum currentNumber =
    if currentMinimum < currentNumber then currentMinimum else currentNumber
  in List.fold_left second_smallest_helper2 (List.hd lst) lst
;;

let delete (x, mylist) = List.filter (fun y -> y != x) mylist;;

let second_smallest myList = 
  let x = second_smallest_helper1 myList in
  let newList = delete (x,myList) in
  second_smallest_helper1 newList
;;
```

Top level `let` binding has the form

```
let <pattern> = <expression>;; (* ;; is optional, but beginners should have it *)
```

but local `let` binding has the form

```
let <pattern> = <expression> in <expression>
```

You absolutely need to use a proper OCaml indentation tool for your editor to avoid this kind of errors.

One more thing. I am not sure your use of `!=` is ok. This is physical pointer comparison. Probably you want to use `<>`, the structural comparison.

> The OP tried to edit and delete all of the answer due to "personal reasons". I myself skipped the edit approval and left it to the community, which apparently rejected it. Meta SO discussion about this kind of thing is found at [What to do when an OP asks to delete my code from my answer?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251923/what-to-do-when-an-op-asks-to-delete-my-code-from-my-answer) , including what the OP should do.

Comment: I agree on the physical/structural comparison. Physical comparison should not be used by beginners.