# Pairwise swap of adjacent elements in OCaml

Tags: ocaml

So far I have

```
let flipeven(listname)=
    let newlist= [] in
    let first=0 in
    let second=1 in 
    let stop= List.length(listname)-1 in
let rec flipevenhelper (x,y)=
if (second<= stop) then
    insert((List.nth(listname) x), newList) in
    insert((List.nth(listname) y), newList) in 
    let second=second+2 in
    let first=first+2 in
    flipevenhelper (first, second)
else
    newList;;
```

But just receive a syntax error at the else statement. What exactly am i doing wrong?

edit:

Here is the insert function

```
let rec insert (x,y) = match (x, y) with
| (x,[ ]) -> x::[]
| (x,y::ys) -> if (x>y) then (y:: insert(x, ys))
    else (x::y::ys);;
```

Comment: I see 3 almost the same OCaml syntax questions recently, like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28688733/what-is-causing-the-syntax-error-here . Before tackling your assignments, install auto-indenter, and learn some introductory OCaml tutorial!!

Answer (score 3):

The `in` keyword is always paired with a `let` keyword. It's not a general way of joining two expressions, which is what you seem to want.

The `;` operator in OCaml *does* join two expressions into a single expression. The first expression is evaluated but then ignored (it should have `unit` type). The second expression is evaluated, and its value is the value of the combined expression.

Note that `;` has lower precedence than `if/then/else` (in some sense). So you should parenthesize the expression after `then` if you use the `;` operator.

Here's a small example:

```
# if 3 > 2 then Printf.printf "yes\n"; 4 else 5;;
Error: Syntax error

# if 3 > 2 then (Printf.printf "yes\n"; 4) else 5;;
yes
- : int = 4
```

After fixing the syntax, you still have many things to fix. In particular, you should realize that variables and lists in OCaml are immutable. You can't insert into your list `newList` just by calling `insert`.

Comment: I tried changing the lines without any lets to have single semi colons but still receive the same error

Comment: You have many errors in your code. I think you can get rid of this syntax error by parenthesizing the code after `then`. But you still have many things to fix. I'll update my answer.